# Does Spring webservice support Java7?

Tags: glassfish-3, java-7, spring-ws, xerces, xalan

We are in the process of upgrading Java version from 1.6 to 1.7 for our Java EE system.
We extensively use spring webservice (1.5.8 in the server side and 2.0.4 in client side).

Initial testing (with java7) shows intermittent problems with web service calls like below
(We using GlassFish 3.1.2.2 on both client and server, recently upgraded)

- Failure 1 (server side log below)

intermittent failure at server side (server springws-1.5.8 and client spring-ws-2.0.4  - Java upgraded from 1.6 to 1.7 on both)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find SAAJ on the classpath
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getImplementation(SaajSoapMessage.java:261)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.<init>(SaajSoapMessage.java:84)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.<init>(SaajSoapMessage.java:70)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:168)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:86)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:86)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
```

As per my analysis, the above problem seems to be caused due to the known issue with spring ws version 1.5.8 - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWS-750 which is fixed in 2.0.4. But before doing the version upgrade, I wanted to be sure that spring ws does officially support Java7. Any idea? 
Anyway this problem seems to get resolved if we revert java version on client side back to 1.6 - suspect that this is related to the versions of xerces/xalan packaged within jdk7

- Failure 2 (server side log below)

We have similar error on another sub-system where server is springws-2.0.4 and client is spring-ws-1.5.8 - Java upgraded from 1.6 to 1.7 on both.

```
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet: Could not complete request
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source:
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getSaajVersion(SaajSoapMessage.java:260)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getImplementation(SaajSoapMessage.java:342)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.<init>(SaajSoapMessage.java:117)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:184)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:58)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

we're using Tomcat7, JDK7 and Spring-WS 2.1.2 and it works.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Are you using this on a production system?

Comment: Yes, we're using it together with Spring-3.1.2 and the Castor Marshaller 1.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

We're using Spring-WS 2.2.3 with Java 8 in a production system deployed on WebLogic and we have no problems. So, I'd say Java 7 is fairly well supported!